# Nginx restful url rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to rewrite URL like this:

```
example.com/demo/test/123/edit
```

To:

```
example.com/demo/test.php?a=123&b=edit
```

It works with this rewrite rule:

```
location /demo {
    rewrite ^/demo/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /demo/$1.php?a=$2&b=$3 last;
}
```

But URL can be /demo/test and /demo/test/123, so rewrite rule doens't work. I tried:

```
rewrite ^/demo/(.*)(?:/*)(.*)(?:/*)(.*) /demo/$1.php?a=$2&b=$3 last;
```

But no luck.

Comment: And ? What will you do if $2 or $3 is empty ?

Comment: Handle this in your application, like most modern web apps do.

Comment: @XavierLucas if #2 and $3 empty its must be skipped with * quantifer. With last rule nginx doesnt match anything.